# Como passar uma variável em php para shell_exec

Tags: php, formulário

Como faço para passar um valor de um input ou select como variável para um shell_exec ?

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form action="speedtest.php" method="POST" id="SpeedTest" class="form">
  <p>
    <label>Quantidade de testes a serem executados: </label>
  </p>
  <input type="tel" name="testes" class="testes" maxlength="1" required>
  <button type="submit" class="qts" value="Executar" onclick="Oculta('main')">Executar</button>
</form>
```

Este formulário faz o envio da quantidade de execuções de testes de velocidade que serão feitas no servidor. Abaixo tenho o script que faz a execução dos testes de velocidade:

```
<?php

shell_exec('/bin/speedtest -l');

?>
```

A variável "valor" que vem do formulário input entraria no meio de "speedtest -l", por exemplo, se preenchesse 2 no input esse número entraria desta forma no shell_exec: speedtest 2 -l

Alguma sugestão de como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Alguém que possa me ajudar com isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que ajude

```
<?php

    $qtdteste = $_POST['testes'];

    shell_exec('/bin/speedtest '.$qtdteste.' -l');
```

Comment: Já tinha conseguido resolver, mas muito obrigado pela resposta, ajudará alguém quando estiver precisando algo parecido como eu.